# AngularJs - datetimepicker open once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a angularJs front end with bootstrap and I am using the datetimepicker component (https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker). It works well the first time, but after the date is selected It is no longer possible to open the component.

the source is in the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rOs5Q2HlIYJrYPkHx7RU)

Can someone help me, please ? Thanks a lot!

The code is the following

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="datetimepicker.css" />
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@1.11.0" data-semver="1.11.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.11.2" data-semver="0.11.2" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dateNow" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
              ng-model="model.date"
            >
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" id="dropdownDate" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
          <datetimepicker data-ng-model="model.date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownDate', minuteStep: 1 }"/>
        </ul>
      </div>


    </div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.model = {
    date: new Date()
  };

});
```

Comment: If you want to make it easy for you, just use the basic HTML5 datepicker.
<input type="date" ng-model="model.cenarioEstresse.periodo.dataInicial">

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting dateStatus to true when you probably want dateStatus.open to be true. Try $scope.dateStatus.open = true; instead of $scope.dateStatus = true; within your open function

Comment: I checked that the $scope.dateStatus.open variable is not being used and I removed it. But the problem remains.

Comment: If you use the ID for the anchor tag instead of dropdownDate for the date-datetimepicker-config it will work i believe. data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dateNow', minuteStep: 1 }"

Comment: I see the version you are using is quite out-of-date. Can you give it a try with the latest version? 

There are no known bugs that have this behavior so it is likely something to do with the markup or javascript.